# How to make the Sharepoint List Preview Pane (right side window) FLOAT when scrolling down webpage?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a preview pane of a list of suppliers. 
The list is vast 100+ items, but when you scroll down the page and hover over a contact further down the list, you cannot see the preview pane because it remains at the top of the page in the webpart.

Anyone know how to keep the left part of the preview pane static (i.e. the supplier name) but have the right side of the preview pane float, so that I can scroll down to a supplier which is further down and display the record to the right of it.

thanks,

Comment: Maybe do some paging on the supplier list to show smaller sets of data?